# Mouse issue in Wine

Tags: wine, mouse

I'm trying to run a FPS game on wine called Vicinity but once the game starts, I can't move the mouse and when I go to the menu the mouse works (in the menu only).
I searched but I didn't find a solution that works for me :(
I have the same problem with another FPS game called OffensiveCombat. The mouse works in the menu but don't in game.

Someone can help me please?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a bug similar to this one: http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20395 and this one: http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=16109

It affects multiple games where, it works in the menu or in a particular part of the game but not when playing it.

Some suggest to install playonlinux: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/

For some games it works perfect with playonlinux, for others, in the example I mentioned do not.

I suggest to first search here for the game: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true

Then the Wine forums or Ubuntu forums. Also make sure you are using the Wine PPA since this one is more up to date. For more information see [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked with Playonlinux :)
The last post here http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=16109 helped me a lot.

Thanks again.