# Installing Dishonored game from disc

Tags: wine, games

I just purchased Dishonored to use on my new linux Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I can not, for the life of me, figure out what to do here to get steam installed with Wine. Every time I attempt to do so, I get a message that tells me I have to install to a hard drive. I have selected the .wine/drive_c directory, but it still tells me it is invalid and not a hard drive thst I am trying to install to. If anyone can give me a hand it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first follow this guide [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine) to the letter. Please make sure that after finishing the guide you end up with a 32-Bit WinePrefix. This should leave you with Wine 1.6 which is the most recent one and with a list of components already installed. The `winetricks list-installed` command in the terminal should look similar to this list:

```
cyrex@cyrex:~$ winetricks list-installed
amstream
d3dcompiler_43
d3dx10
d3dx11_42
d3dx11_43
d3dx9_26
d3dx9_28
d3dx9_31
d3dx9_35
d3dx9_36
d3dx9_39
d3dx9_42
d3dx9_43
d3dx9
devenum
dirac
directmusic
directplay
directx9
dmsynth
dotnet20
dotnet40
dsound
ffdshow
icodecs
l3codecx
mfc42
mspatcha
msscript
msvcirt
physx
quartz
vcrun2008
vcrun2010
vcrun6sp6
vcrun6
winhttp
wininet
wsh56vb
wsh57
xact_jun2010
xact
xinput
xna40
```

Of this list, to have Dishonored working, even with all DLC installed, you need to have at least the following components from the list above:

```
d3dx11_43
d3dx9_26
d3dx9_28
d3dx9_31
d3dx9_35
d3dx9_36
d3dx9_39
d3dx9_42
d3dx9_43
d3dx9
directmusic
directplay
directx9
dotnet40
dsound
mfc42
mspatcha
msscript
msvcirt
physx
quartz
vcrun2008
vcrun2010
vcrun6sp6
vcrun6
winhttp
wininet
wsh56vb
wsh57
xact_jun2010
xact
xinput
xna40
```

Now simply run the installer and you should see the following:

[image]

Start the installer and when it finishes it is important to check the options that matter:

[image]

After which you should be able to simply play the game. My recommendations are to play the game in Windows 7 mode because in Windows XP sometimes there are keyboard keys stuck and sound issues. The end result should be like this:

[image]

Here is a video showing how Dishonored will look: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5u-cxCGG9Y

Comment: I am always getting the SHA1sum error for some of the dll installations. Even though I have tried renaming the file and directory name the same things recurs. Any guidance?

Comment: @shivisuper - Need to provide Wine version and more information about version of ubuntu and anything else related. Else nobody will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

.wine/drive_c is a Linux directory, not a windows directory, hence the error message.  You have to run the installer with wine and point it to a directory within wine, using Windows based filesystem (looks like C:\ ).

I don't know much about wine but I have a really advanced setup where I have a "wine version" of steam that accesses the steamapps folder in my windows partition, even though steam itself is installed and running on the Linux partition.

I used playonlinux to get my games running.  It has tons of user friendly features and sets up all the wine dependencies and packages for you when you install a game from their list of known working applications.  You can also install non-listed apps and games manually through playonlinux.

Install playonlinux from the Software Centre, and when installing your first game it will take you through a set up wizard that let's you choose what version of wine to use, and some settings to choose regarding the wine directory it makes.  The wine directories for playonlinux are in different locations than with just Wine, so you might as well uninstall old wine to save space.

I find the most success with running windows games using the 1.5.2 stable release of Wine.  Steam will run on most of the wine versions though, and Steam is a listed application for playonlinux, so it should install perfectly first try.  Good luck!

Comment: Once you get stream running I assume you can figure out the rest :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the help, thats great! You're a scholar and a gentleman, thanks for your help :)