# Is it possible to install the Sims 3 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on an iMac. I have all the specific requirements to play the game, as I have done on this mac before. I'm just wondering if it's possible to run it on Ubuntu?

Comment: You need to tells us more information or we wont be able to help you. Like, How do you plan to install the software? On what media form do you have the software? Do you want a native Ubuntu version or is a wine version ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to follow this guide: [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

After that you need to look for the components The Sims 3 needs to install. I already posted a review for it in [WineHQ DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16664&iTestingId=79051). You also need to check if you have the hardware requirements for it. For information about this see: http://www.thesims3.com/game/systemreq
Lastly, the winetricks components I had installed when I tested to see if the Sims 3 was working (Not all of them are needed) were:

```
cyrex@cyrex:~$ winetricks list-installed
amstream
d3dcompiler_43
d3dx10
d3dx11_42
d3dx11_43
d3dx9_26
d3dx9_28
d3dx9_31
d3dx9_35
d3dx9_36
d3dx9_39
d3dx9_42
d3dx9_43
d3dx9
devenum
dirac
directmusic
directplay
directx9
dmsynth
dotnet20
dotnet40
dsound
ffdshow
icodecs
l3codecx
mfc42
mspatcha
msscript
msvcirt
physx
quartz
vcrun2008
vcrun2010
vcrun6sp6
vcrun6
winhttp
wininet
wsh56vb
wsh57
xact_jun2010
xact
xinput
xna40
```

The game works perfectly. I recommend running the game from the terminal first to see what the game needs (If there is anything it needs, it will tell you through the terminal, for example "Missing .NET Framework 4.0). The game also works best with Windows 7 selected on the winecfg application. It also works with Windows XP but I feel it looks or runs faster on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can install it from Play on Linux, here have [more info](http://www.maketecheasier.com/play-the-sims3-in-linux/2010/11/18)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.