# Wine Sound Issues (DirectX Games Only)

Tags: sound, 13.10, wine, games

Title kind of says the issue.

Whenever I run an application such as Mari0, which doesn't use DirectX, sound is perfectly fine, but when I run apps such as Runner 2 or LIMBO, which uses DirectX, the sound has issues, and sounds slowed down and laggy.

I'm also using Play on Linux to install my games. Both those games ran perfectly when I first installed them, but now I'm having that issue. The games work perfectly except for the sound.

Any suggestions?

Specs:

> - PC: HP Compaq Pro 6305
> - RAM: 4GB (3.3 GB usable by Ubuntu)
> - OS: Ubuntu 13.10 x64

Comment: Please read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine you have a couple of issues which can come from the fact that you are using a 64 bit OS and wine 64 has sound issues with that. Another is games like Limbo and Runner work better on wine 32 with the winetricks directx9 installed (and a couple of more things). All of which you can find on how to solve in the link provided. Even if both games do not mention what is needed I have provided a complete winetricks installation for almost all cases.

Comment: Just an added note, some games don't run well with wine and the pulse subsystem.  There are winetricks to force alsa for realtime or closer to realtime sound processing.  Check out the playonlinux scripts for some of the late 90s games.  Lots of them use an old wine version with a force alsa patch.