# MS Word error message under Wine HQ

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, winetricks

I had installed MS Word through Wine on my Ubuntu Desktop. It work perfectly.

But everytime when I run MS Word 07 I have error message. If close this a error window. Word still runs and works fine.

[image]

How to fix this pesky message ?

Comment: No no. I installed MS Word. And it work but some wrong.

Comment: Is it possible for you to view or select the rest of the line that starts with `Program:`? If the specific `.dll` (or other) file where the error is happening can be found, that might make it easier to figure out exactly what version of the ["C runtime library"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (in this case, the MSVC runtime) is being loaded and/or other relevant information. Then this problem could likely be solved with `winetricks` by installing the appropriate missing library/libraries (or uninstalling the wrong ones that are being confused for the right ones, maybe...).

Comment: It solve through **winetricks**. But which missing a library me need to install ?

Comment: What did you did with winetricks?

Comment: @Braiam Nothing

Comment: Did you followed the WineHQ guide? http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12811

Comment: @Braiam No. You can help me fix this message. It's error message pop-up when I run Photoshop too.

Comment: @Braiam I install and configure Wine using this [guide](http://askubuntu.com/q/316025/181228)

Comment: That is the basic of the basic. You must follow the guide on WineHQ. It may solve most of the problems you could be facing...