# Cant install WINE

Tags: apt, wine, software-installation

Have problem to install wine 1.6 or 1.7 doesn`t matter.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.11-0ubuntu1~saucy1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Before I reinstalled Ubuntu all was OK. I have tried a lot advises but nothing helps.

Comment: Hi Kvach, after looking on how to resolve the unmet dependencies please see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Comment: I checked it before, didn`t help me :(

Comment: You need to first solve the unmet dependency as mentioned In the duplicate question. Then you can proceed in installing wine. Did you do the unmet dependency first?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: @Luis Alvarado yes, I did, but doesn`t work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this message occurs if you forget to run update before you install new packages.  Try updating your index files and update your system with

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After it finishes, try installing wine again.  If you still get this problem, you may actually have held packages so you should hop over to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) question, the first answer will show you how to identify which packages may be the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I did that all.