# Steam(Windows) on Ubuntu 12.04 using PlayOnLinux

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to run Steam (Windows) through PlayOnLinux. I get it to start, I log in, steam sends me an e-mail with a code to register with my computer, I type it in, and steam crashes. It does this every time I try to log in. I am new to Linux, so please dumb this down for me.

Comment: There is a bug in Wine which makes Steam crash - upgrade your Wine to > 1.7.8 (through ppa): http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was opening up PlayOnLinux-->Tools-->Manage Wine Versions. I added Wine 1.7.11, closed that window, clicked on steam, clicked on configure, picked Wine 11.7.11 from the Wine Version drop down and I was able to run steam after that.