# Can't install WINE - "broken packages"

Tags: apt, wine, package-management

I can't install WINE. When I go to the terminal and type `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`, I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.12-0ubuntu1~saucy1)
           Recommends: winbind
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've looked around here on AskUbuntu, and haven't found a solution to the problem. I tried going into Synaptic and going to `Edit --> Fix Broken Packages`, but this doesn't fix the problem. I've tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get update`, but those do not solve the issue either. I've tried adding the WINE PPA, but that doesn't work either.

This issue started after trying to install `netflix-desktop` from the `ppa:ehoover/compholio` PPA. After I installed this, an icon appeared in my panel telling me of a problem involving `wine1.7:i386` not being in the cache. I had this problem once before, so I uninstalled WINE and removed the PPA, but now WINE won't install at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine)?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` in a terminal window?

Comment: @Wilf I'm not able to get past the `sudo apt-get install wine` part. The same as above happens.

Comment: @Marc yes, I have.

Comment: How about `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: If the issue started with that `ppa:ehoover/compholio` PPA, it may be that some packages from that PPA remain installed on your system and conflict with Wine somehow. You could try a `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:ehoover/compholio` in order to revert all packages that may have been installed by that PPA to official packages.