# How to install Bad Piggies on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I am completely new with `Wine`. I haven't installed any games through `Wine`. What are the steps to install [Bad piggies](http://www.badpiggies.com/) on `Ubuntu 12.04`?

Comment: @Danatela for Wine related questions, please point them to http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine which is a complete guide about Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wine is not complicated but some games or Applications might not work as expected since Wine is NOT an emulator :)

To install normally you do

`sudo apt-get install wine`

to install application:
`wine Setup.exe`

then if everything went ok you should have the Application/Game installed on your wine directory which as a similar layout as in Windows.

`cd ~/.wine/drive_c/`

then go to the path of the Application/Game

```
cd Program\ Files\ApplicationXYZ
```

and run `wine *Executable.exe*`

For more instructions and help on Bad Piggies with Wine, follow this [page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26748) which the Wine community maintain.

*EDIT*

Also as an alternative, since Bad Piggies should not have a big 3D and CPU requirements you could also try to run it on a Virtual Machine. This is usually more easy and if you have a powerful machine you should get also a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PlayOnLinux. It's available in the software center and has nice GUI menus to assist you in installing games like this. If your game is not listed, just choose the option to install a game that isn't listed.

Comment: Why not playing the game online: http://www.puffgames.com/games/bad-piggies-2/