# couldn't install wine

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wine

I wanted to install wine, but then it gave me this message:

"To install wine, this package has to be removed:

Nvida opencl driver and icd loader library"

can anyone help me with this? and how can I remove this package?

Comment: This is a good starting point: [Installing and Configuring Wine](http://askubuntu.com/q/316025/65926).

Answer (score 0):

Just press `Install Anyway`. If it isn't showing - use terminal ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

---

If you want specific wine version type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine*.*
```

Where `*.*` is the version (like `wine1.5`)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try to install from Ubuntu Software Center .
Look for Wine Windows Program Loader it has a glass with red wine as a thumbnail .
The gui will guide you to remove the package if still necessary.

If you install it you can use with right click in the file(.exe propably) and choose wine etc..

If you are looking for the installed files after the installation , they can be found in home folder(hidden files , disable with Ctrl + H ) . Inside the .wine folder you will find
a windows structure .

I hope it helps !