# Why can an application installed using Wine not access NTFS partitions?

Tags: wine, ntfs

Ubuntu was installed alongside Windows 7 on my system. After some days, I deleted and formatted the Windows partition and didn't format the other NTFS partitions.

Before that, I installed Wine on my Ubuntu. I used it to install some software like Picasa. When I tried to open some images on a NTFS partition using Picasa, I was unable to view or access these partitions. I will show my partition details -

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

As you see, I have 4 NTFS partitions in total. When I opened Picasa and searched for the partitions in which the images are saved, I was unable to find some partitions (sda5, sda6 and sda7).

[image: Picasa open image dialog]

This is the window that was opened by Picasa when I tried to search image files. How can I access the partitions in which the images are stored from Picasa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wine, trying to mimic how the drive letter works in Windows, also includes the Z: letter for the root file system on Ubuntu as shown in the **Drives** option in the `winecfg`:

[image]

Just open `winecfg` and go to the **Drives** tab to see which letters are assigned to which folders.

A quick example of how Z: looks if I try to search on it:

[image]

As you can see, from here I can navigate to **media** and find the NTFS partition from there. In your case it would be in `/media/tomin/...`. You can also add new letters that point to a specific folder, like letter D: if you wanted to point directly to the NTFS partition.

As Takkat mentioned something VERY important in the comments, Wine can not mount a file system (Mounting is a Ubuntu system action, not so much a Wine option). So you need to first mount the file system, via File/Nautilus for example, and then proceed to use the Wine app you need.

Comment: As you said, I found Z/media/tomin. But I have a doubt - the second image you shown in answer, Import Registry File, where does that window came from ? I can't find such a window from my Wine Configuration.

Comment: That is regedit, another wine command. For more wine commands see chapter 10 in http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine

Answer (score 4):

`C:` drive shown to you in Wine, is **not a real partition** but actually a **regular folder** exists in your Linux home directory.

If you execute the command below in Terminal, you will see the corresponding folder for Wine's `C:`

> nautilus $HOME/.wine/

[image]

If you need to access real partitions (which are shown in gParted) through Wine:

1. First click on the partition you desire to access from the file manager. (Clicking on it will mount it.)
2. Then go to `/media/$USER/...` directory from a Wine application. There you will be able access real partitions available in your system.

[image: wine-explorer]

Comment: What do you mean by - "First click on the partition you desire to access from the file manager. (Clicking on it will mount it.)" in you answer ? I didn't get that ? Can you explain a little further ?

Comment: When you open the file manager, on the left panel you can see `Devices`. You have to click on the partition you need to access under devices. Clicking on it will make the partition accessible and mounted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

These are good answers.  Also note in Gparted /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda5 are not mounted.
There is about 1 GB of data between them, and maybe those are the files you are looking for?

You can edit those paritions inside Gparted and set a mount point so that they will always be available.  Right click the partition in the text list and select properties (I think that's the menu entry).  You specify the mount point.  But the change will not apply until you hit the green check mark at the top of Gparted.

Comment: How to mount those partitions ? I right clicked those NTFS partitions, but the Mount option is not active.