# Picasa installed using Wine is unable to access some NTFS partitions?

Tags: wine, ntfs, google-picasa

Recently I installed Picasa in my Ubuntu 14.04 using Wine. After performing a Wine configuration I was able to access all the images in the NTFS partitions on my hard disk. **I performed Wine configuration as said in [Why can an application installed using Wine not access NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475255/why-can-an-application-installed-using-wine-not-access-ntfs-partitions).**

After 3 days, it became unable to access 2 NTFS partitions. But I can access 1 NTFS partition(named E, see image below).

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I am unable to expand both D and F. How can I fix this issue permanently ?

Comment: As said in a mentioned Q&A, your drives are not mounted. To have them mounted, you should specify mount points for them. This can be done either through `/etc/fstab` or Gparted.

Comment: @Danatela  How to mount those drives permanently ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/45607/how-to-mount-partition-permanently

Comment: The link suggested tells about mounting ext4 partition. Is the same can be done to mount NTFS partition ? If not, tell me how ?

Comment: Just replace `ext4` with `ntfs`.