# wine program not running in fullscreen

Tags: windows, wine

So I'm fairly new to wine, and I'm having a problem with a few programs that don't want to run in fullscreen. The menu bar remains, the mouse doesn't move all the way to the left and the gray bar at the top of the screen remains as well.

[Screen shot](http://postimg.org/image/ob919g4n9/)

Also, the screen will scroll. Is there any way to remedy this?

I'm using wine 1.6.2, and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Untick "Emulate a virtual desktop" in winecfg. See 6.7. in https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine/316029#316029