# Wine and .bat file - can ony run from a different directory

Tags: wine

I have [Power Prep II](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/powerprep2/pc_download) working well Wine in Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity). I simply navigate to the directory of the **launch.bat** file and type `wine start launch.bat` —voila, everything works excellently. (In fact, I can hardly say "*I've* got" because I did no actual work.)

The issue is, when I move up one directory and type something like `wine start "POWER PREP II/launch.bat"`, I get an error:

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"FoxitCloudUpdateService"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000000,(nil),0x0002,0x00000000,0x74e958,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
```

This came about because I'm trying to create a .desktop icon on my sidebar.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run it like this, assuming the POWER PREP II folder is in Program Files:

```
wine start /d "C:\\Program Files\\POWER PREP II" launch.bat
```

This would first set the current folder to  **C:\Program Files\POWER PREP II** followed by executing the **launch.bat** file.

There is an excellent example in [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-wine)