# Installing .exe app on ubuntu

Tags: games

i am asking if i can install .exe (GTA IV) on my ubuntu from 2  DVD ( using wine ), does it require any other programs ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct Wine, Winetricks, the correct GTA version and a special patch.

1. Obtain a Steam-less version of `GTA IV Title Update 7`;
2. [Obtain and install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-wine) `Wine 1.7.22` and the latest `Winetricks`;
3. Install and patch GTA with the [XLiveLess Patch](http://www.gtavision.com/?section=downloads&site=download&id=2914);
4. **Backup the .wine directory in your Home;**
5. Execute the following commands in a terminal (`xterm` is OK, those actions should make the game more stable):

   rm -fr ~/.wine

   export WINEARCH=win32

   export WINEPREFIX="/home/**YOURUSERNAME**/.wine"

   winecfg
6. Install the following common packages with `Winetricks`:

   d3dx10

   d3dx9_26

   d3dx9_28

   d3dx9_31

   d3dx9_35

   d3dx9_36

   d3dx9_39

   d3dx9_42

   d3dx9_43

   d3dx9

   directx9

   dotnet20sp1

   dotnet20

   dotnet30sp1

   dotnet35

   dotnet40

   gfw

   mfc40

   mfc42

   msxml3

   msxml4

   msxml6

   physx

   quartz

   vb6run

   vcrun2003

   vcrun2005

   vcrun2008

   vcrun2010

   vcrun6sp6

   vcrun6

   wmp10

   wsh56vb

   wsh57

   xact_jun2010

   xact

   xinput

   xna40
7. Play, like in the [demonstrative video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-wine).
8. If the game hangs, set the Wine enviroment to "Windows XP".

Some textures might disappear and you may find occasional lag spikes or freezes during your gameplay; save your game often and backup your savegames from time to time.
You will not be able to play online and this guide may not work on pirated (and customized) copies; always buy a game if you really like it.

Please, feel free to comment under here or on [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22316) if you have more questions and don't forget to press the left UP arrow and mark as favorite if I'm of any help.

Have a nice day.