# Diablo 3 and Starcraft 2 fullscreen with system bar ( ubuntu 14.04 )

Tags: 14.04, wine, games, playonlinux, fullscreen

I'm running diablo 3 and starcraft 2 , and when my game starts, the system bar is showing up on the fullscreen but before the game open in the desktop of the wine the bar does not appear.

I want to play on fullscreen without the system bars.

System: Ubuntu 14.04
PlayOnLinux 4.2.5
Wine 1.7.22 on Starcraft II
Wine 1.7.15 on Diablo III

Comment: Weird because with Wine 1.7.26 I am getting right now fullscreen (No Unity Launcher Icons or System Bar showing). Testing Starcraft 2 and Diablo 3 from a friend. What video card are you using, video drivers and anything else that can help.

Comment: I'm using GeForce GTX 660Ti.
Playing World of warcraft on Wine 1.7.15 is normal with fullscreen (No Unity Launcher Icons or System Bar showing)

Comment: In my case I have a normal 440 (Not a monster like yours), but I recommend updating Wine with the wine ppa. You should have 1.7.26, then proceed to test and let us know. More info in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-wine

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing that you could try is to configure your bar to hide  it itself automatically.

Right click in your panel, go to `Settings` and configure the `auto-hide` property.