# New, Clueless, and needing help with Wine

Tags: wine, software-center, games

So, long story short I have been a user of Windows since I can remember. I forcefully had to switch to Ubuntu the last few days because of a long-winded issue dealing with my Windows/key. But we will not focus on that.

I want to really give Ubuntu a chance. I know it can be a good OS. Problem is, while I am willing to learn and understand, I am also as clueless as a newborn baby to this and I need some serious help, tutorials, walk-through.

I am also in a slight panic because in order to install Ubuntu, my brother had to take out my graphics card because we kept getting a gray screen. Once that was out and my monitor was connected to my on-board graphics, we had no issues with install.

Alright, so once I do get a basic rundown of what I am doing, I still have the issue of I cannot figure out how to download/install programs. I was looking at installing Wine so I hope I can install Battle.net and being able to play WoW as well as being able to use my Photoshop. I was hoping to have it done before Thursday since the new WoW expansion is releasing, but I know that may not be possible right now until I get my graphics card back in and working with Ubuntu, and also get Wine figured out.

So, when I use Ubuntu Software Center to try to install Wine, I get an error: *"Failed to download repository information" - Please check your Internet connection. Details lists a bunch of code.*

When I look on WIneHQ's website, it has a section that states:

"Open the Software Sources menu by launching the Ubuntu Software Center and selecting Edit->Software Sources. Choose the Other Software tab and click Add."

Problem is, I don't see an "Edit". So I am a bit frustrated. So help on figuring this out and any other basic information would be amazing. I really do want to give Ubuntu a chance and I don't have the funds to fork out to get Windows again right now so I figured it is best to make of what I have and just go with it.

Installed 
Ubuntu 13.04
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G3240 @ 3.10GHz × 2 
Graphics Card: ASUS HD6670

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 has reached it's end of life and is no longer supported. Installing a newer release (14.04 LTS or 14.10) will definfitely give you a much better experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Answer (score 1):

The wineHQ webpage for Ubuntu download has not been updated in a while.
You can however install wine by typing the following into a terminal window.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

For more information on how to get Battle.net/WoW to work in Wine, please consult the WineHQ database for the battle.net applocation here: [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28855)

PS: World of Warcraft should work from the same setup as the battle.net application.

PPS: ubuntu 13.04 is no longer supported. Better update to 14.04 or 14.10. :)

Comment: Says tha tsome packages could not be installed. "This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: yeah. You are using a non-supported version of ubuntu. You need to update to 14.04 or 14.10 before installing anything. :)

Comment: Okay, I feel like a dummy. How do I update?

Comment: It just said "Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection" :(

Comment: It's probably easier to just do a clean install of 14.04.  If you search askubuntu for "upgrade 13.04 to 14.04" you'll see this advice frequently.

Comment: Thank you! Updating to 14.04 worked and I got Wine installed! :)