# Unable to play "Prince of Persia: Warrior Within" on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: games

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a quad core i3 processor. I have downloaded Prince of Persia
and installed it.

When I click `princeofpersia.exe` the game opens, but the screen becomes parted and the screen appears broken and the game does not run.

Comment: Which one? Forgotten sands?

Answer (score 9):

Windows Binaries(`.exe`, `.msi`) cannot be executed under Ubuntu(Linux). For that, you need Wine to be installed under Ubuntu. [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/) is a compatibility layer, that adds a Windows shell in your Ubuntu. Meaning: it enables you to run Windows binaries. For the security risks Wine brings, please see: [Do Wine Viruses only work while Wine is running?](https://askubuntu.com/a/562396/36315).

On how to install [Prince Of Persia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia), we will use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/)...

### PlayOnLinux:

> PlayOnLinux is a graphical front-end for the Wine software compatibility layer which allows Linux users to install Windows-based video games, as well as many other applications such as Apple iTunes, Safari, Microsoft Office, Microsoft Internet Explorer.

PlayOnLinux supports all of the Prince Of Persia games.

### Install:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

### Search and do what the wizard says:

[image: League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes]

     <sup>Image from: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu).</sup>

**Reference**:

- [Prince Of Persia: Original - PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-121-Prince_Of_Persia__Original.html)
- [Prince of Persia: Sands of Time - PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-128-Prince_of_Persia__Sands_of_Time.html)
- [Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands - PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-690-Prince_of_Persia__The_Forgotten_Sands.html)
- [Prince of Persia: The Two Thrones - PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-485-Prince_of_Persia__The_Two_Thrones.html)
- [Prince of Persia: Warrior Within - PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-134-Prince_of_Persia__Warrior_Within.html)
- [Prince of Persia: 2008 - PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-358-Prince_of_Persia_2008.html)