# How do I remove the brontok virus that has infected my Ubuntu via Wine?

Tags: command-line, wine, malware, removing

My laptop runs on Ubuntu and was recently infected with the [brontok virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brontok) it managed to infect my Ubuntu - through my flash drive - because I have Wine installed. I had used the USB in an infected Windows computer belonging to someone I know. It creates `.exe` files in random application folders.

I've found `.exe` files in the folder for Openshot video editor, Audacity, Wine, it sometimes creates an `.exe` file in my Desktop folder, it creates the classic Brontok image with the green background in my Pictures folder as an HTML file and if I delete these, they just reappear each time I switch my computer back on.

I can't even name all the folders this worm is making `.exe` files in. They're all over and deleting doesn't help. A comprehensive guide on how to remove it is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will show you how to delete wine and the virus it self, step by step:

**Step One**:

Run the following command(s) in your terminal:

This will `purge` wine from your system:

- `sudo apt-get purge wine`

**Step Two**:

Just in case `apt-get` could not delete a Wine `.exe` file for whatever reason, delete the entire `wine` folder. It resides in your home folder like so: `.wine/`

- `sudo rm -rfv ~/.wine/`

**Step Three**:

To make sure no wine process is still loaded:

- `sudo reboot`

This will reboot your system, without confirmation.

You can run the following command after the reboot to see which `.exe` process is still loaded:

```
ps aux | grep .exe
```

And then force close it:

```
killall -9 brontok.exe
```

Make sure you know that the process is malicious.

**Step Four**:

Run this in your home folder, it will try to find any file that ends with the `.exe` prefix.

- `find ~/ -type f -name "*.exe"`

**Step Five**:

The previous find command will display the path of the `.exe` file(s), delete every `.exe` file you don't trust. Like so:

- `sudo rm -f /path/to/maybe-a-virus.exe`

**Step Six**:

Scan with an Antivirus for linux, like clam antivirus. How to install and scan here:

- [security - How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/560947/36315)

**Notes**:

`clamav` does not have a large database of Windows viruses compared to the mayor Antivirus Corporations. If you are not a hundred percent convinced of the legality of a file, you can upload it to:

- [VirusTotal - Free Online Virus, Malware and URL Scanner](https://www.virustotal.com/)

At the time of writing, it use 57 anti viruses to scan files. Its still not a hundred percent accurate, but, it is right for about 99% of the time. My personal experience.

[Mono](http://www.monodevelop.com/) names its binaries to `.exe`, So, not all `.exe` files you don't know, are harmful. For a list of Linux projects that use mono, see:

- [Mono (software) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia#Software_developed_with_Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Software_developed_with_Mono)

Here is a quote - my own - that comments about the security benefits from using PlayOnLinux:

> "My preferred graphical front-end for Wine is PlayOnLinux, with that you have more control over your Wine environment, and there is a separate environment per application. So, if you happened to get infected by using Safari, use the Configuration options to examine and/or restore, or just delete the entire Safari Volume." - [blade19899](https://askubuntu.com/users/36315/blade19899), [malware - Do Wine Viruses only work while Wine is running?](https://askubuntu.com/a/562396/36315)

It's a bit safer than using wine.

**Step Seven**:

*After you're absolutely sure that your virus is gone*, re-install wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

---

**Links**:

- [malware - Do Wine Viruses only work while Wine is running? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/562396/36315)
- [VirusTotal - Free Online Virus, Malware and URL Scanner](https://www.virustotal.com/)
- [Mono (software) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia#Software_developed_with_Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Software_developed_with_Mono)
- [security - How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/560947/36315)

Comment: I would recommend deleting every single .exe, even if you "trust" it.

Comment: @jrg Some application use mono, mono names binaries .exe. So, banshee uses mono, if you delete all the .exe files, you risk breaking software that are legit.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it could work, I only have one question - If I follow these instructions, I'm assuming I won't be able to run wine any more (it will be deleted, after all). That's a problem for me, I use wine. Can I just re-install wine after doing this?

Comment: @Deisie yes you can reinstall wine, if you are absolutely sure you deleted the virus. As I mentioned in my answer, its slightly saver so use PlayOnLinux.

Comment: I did what you said (amazingly enough, I managed), but I'm finding it difficult to install clamav. I downloaded it, and extracted the zip folder, but when I type the command, I just get this:

Comment: Reading state information... Done
Package clamav is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'clamav' has no installation candidate
mylaptop@Mylaptop-Laptop:~$

Comment: @Deisie, you can install clamav because you are running a version of Ubuntu thats no longer supported. That being said, you can skip clamav. And upload `.exe` files that you find suspicious. There are other Anti viruses that you can try to install, but, not sure if they support outdated Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @Deisie: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**  And you should [read this as well](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe)

Comment: @blade19899, I know it's a been a lifetime since I asked the question, but I finally came back today and realised I hadn't accepted the answer yet. I've accepted it now. Thank you for all your help, your instructions did in fact, remove the virus. Luckily I eventually get around to updating my Ubuntu altogether, so now I can install new programs and stuff.

Comment: @Deisie No problem. Glad to be off help!