# Trying to remove brontok virus, don't understand output of 'ps aux | grep .exe'

Tags: windows, malware

I have what I think is the brontok virus. Trying to remove it following this post [How do I remove the brontok virus that has infected my Ubuntu via Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639513/how-do-i-remove-the-brontok-virus-that-has-infected-my-ubuntu-via-wine)

I entered the command ps aux | grep .exe after removing wine to see a list of running .exe processes but I don't understand the output. Is there a process running here that I could kill?

```
sam@congo-bongo-i:~$ ps aux | grep .exe 
sam 2028  0.0  0.1  352400   8740 ?       Sl    11:52    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0 
sam 2609  0.0  0.0   16016    924 pts/2   S+    11:54    0:00 grep --color=auto .exe
```

I'm obviously very unfamiliar with command line stuff so please be gentle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ps aux command is listing all processes and is chained with grep command which is looking for .exe string in the output of the ps command. After any exe processes are found kill them using sudo kill process_number. The process_number will be in the output of your chained ps aux|grep .exe command.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you responded before I realised I'd made the above post without adding the output. I've edited it now and wondered if youd be kind enough to take another look.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed the above post, skipped the section on killing .exe processes and manually searched for and deleted the .exe files in nautilus. Seems okay now.