# Instaling Zerodha Trader or zerodha PI

Tags: software-installation

i have installed wine later tried instaling Zerdha trader (Nest) is opening but showing error, Pi is not at all opening.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information by [edit]ing your question and telling us: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the error message is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information... (Please help us help you!)

Answer (score 1):

To install Zerodha Pi you need,

1. Microsoft .NET Framework 4(x86 and x64)
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries(x86)
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries(x86)

---

### Step 1 :

First of all Install `wine` and `winetricks`.

**wine :** using ppa for latest version.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

**winetricks :**

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

---

### Step 2 :

Most of the Windows apps work on 32 Bit. So you have to create a 32 Bit wineprefix by following commands,

```
rm -fr ~/.wine  
export WINEARCH="win32"
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/
```

Now you can install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 using `winetricks` as,

```
winetricks dotnet40
```

---

### Step 3:

I suppose you have already downloaded `Zerodha Pi` from  Zerodha q-back office with the activation key. Extract `pi.zip` in the `Downloads` directory and you will get a directory `pi`. There you can find `Pi_setup.exe`. Run the following command to install it,

```
wine ~/Downloads/pi/Pi_setup.exe
```

Before installing `Pi` you can see the system would install `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008` and `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010`.

At last step `Pi` will be installed and a desktop icon will be created.  Just Log in with your credentials, answer those two security questions. Then `Pi` will ask for the activation key. Just put it to activate. ***Happy Trading.***

---

For more information please look at,

1. [Running .Net 4.0 application with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548909/running-net-4-0-application-with-wine)
2. [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine?lq=1)

Comment: I have tried it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS today. Everything gets installed but, when I click on the Pi icon the program doesn't gets launched. Any idea what should look into?

Comment: sorry @Imdad.. I struggled much to make this happen.. But could not solve this and switched to kite..