# I can't install an exe on wine because of missing mscoree.dll... help please!

Tags: wine, 64-bit, microsoft

**The Problem**

I tried installing lghub.exe (the logitech gaming driver) using wine but encountered this problem:

```
tom@Trinity:~$ wine /home/tom/Downloads/lghub_installer.exe
002c:err:module:fixup_imports_ilonly mscoree.dll not found, IL-only binary L"lghub_installer.exe" cannot be loaded
002c:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\tom\\Downloads\\lghub_installer.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

It seems like .net frame was not installed properly...

**My software**

- wine-5.0 64-bit architecture
- wine OS: windows 7
- OS: ubuntu

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following in hopes of a clean reinstall of .net4.0

- uninstalling the .wine folder, purging wine, rebooting wine to create another .wine folder, running command: `winetricks dotnet40` and finally launching command `wine /home/tom/Downloads/lghub_installer.exe` again. which only resulted in the same error.
- I also tried creating a 32bit .wine folder by following the instructions posted here ([Running .Net 4.0 application with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548909/running-net-4-0-application-with-wine)). However, the exe file cannot be run in a 32-bit prefix because the exe is 64-bit and no 32-bit exe exists.

**Conclusion**

Surely there must be a way for a 64-bit wine to cleanly download and install .net4.0!!  Please help!