# How to configure wine to install Evernote?

Tags: wine, 14.10, evernote

What are the DLL's that I have to install before trying Evernote?

I was looking for a detailed answer like this one : [How to install and configure wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-do-i-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: May be you would like to see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/657753/299538

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install Evernote is to install PlayOnLinux first, then download the Evernote executable, then open PlayOnLinux and install Evernote as an "other application".

However, lately, Evernote under Wine has been complaining that it can't reach the server. This is supposed to be due to a lack of support of TLS. PlayOnLinux may be able to correct this, but I'm not sure about that.