# Is Baidu browser available for Ubuntu?

Tags: browser, alternative

In the [Ubuntu Desktop feature](https://web.archive.org/web/20141222024806/http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/features/web-browsing), there is a picture if you hover on it, it displays "Baidu".

[image: Baidu browser icon on Ubuntu website in 2014]

I searched but never found any baidu browser for Ubuntu. I use chrome but i really want to try a new browser. Is there really any Baidu browser available for Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe something special for Kylin?

Comment: You might be right @muru

Comment: This dated post has been bumped by community for more than ten times ([see timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/589931/timeline)), and nobody seems to do anything with it. The web content has since changed, but I fix that link with screenshot already.

Answer (score 1):

Baidu Browser is currently not available for Ubuntu.

If you want to install Baidu Browser on Ubuntu, you can [install it via WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine).