# Game not showing correctly, Graphics Card Issues?

Tags: graphics, games, intel

I'm trying to play Cities Skyline on my laptop but am having graphics issues (all though frame rate appears to be ok). For example when I start a game images of base map don't show, I can't see roads when building them, water is black etc. Is this an Issues with my graphics card/ drivers? How can I tell if they are working correctly?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 TLS 64 Bits Processor: Intel i7 Graphics Card: Intergrated RAM: 8GB

Comment: How do you play it? I mean Wine, Steam etc... if it's Wine make sure you have installed all the libraries dlls etc required by the game because you just might be missing packages in Wine prefix. http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Comment: Playing with steams Linux client