# How to install missing MSXML 5.0 DLL in ubuntu 14.04lts

Tags: software-installation

How do I install the missing MSXML 5.0 for office 2007 which I installed using wine in ubuntu 14.04lts. I have the MSXML 5.0 DLL file.

Comment: We can't support individual wine installations on this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install and configure Wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: While I don't agree with the idea that we can't provide specific help with people's Wine problems, in this case [it does look like a bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30785). (Maybe that will help, I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 4):

Try installing Office 2007 using playonlinux. It asks you where the installation files are and automatically gets everything you need. To install playonlinux, run "sudo apt-get install playonlinux". Find Office 2007 in the list, click install, and follow the instructions.