# How to download facebook videos by using 'youtube-dl' in linux?

Tags: command-line, youtube-dl

I am unable to download Facebook video using `youtube-dl`. The following error occurs during downloading:

```
$ youtube-dl https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983&set=vb.107925785982&type=2&theater
[1] 5101
[2] 5102
[3] 5103
theater: command not found
[2]-  Done                    set=vb.107925785982
[3]+  Done                    type=2
[2]-  Done                    set=vb.107925785982
[3]+  Done                    type=2
$ [generic] video: Requesting header

$ WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] video: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>

[1]+  Exit 1                  youtube-dl
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using `youtube-dl` try to clean up the URL you use.  For example, the following URL *will* work.  Thanks for the video ^_~.

- https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983

How did you install `youtube-dl`?  If you installed it through `apt`, I would recommend the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install $(apt-cache depends youtube-dl | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo pip install youtube-dl
```

`pip` seems to have a more up-to-date version.

Some characters need to be escaped to prevent issues.  You can single-quote your URL to help prevent these issues:

- `youtube-dl 'https://domain.tld/path/file.ext'`

Comment: mrn@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~$ youtube-dl https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983
[generic] video: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] video: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
mrn@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~$

Comment: this is also not work.

Comment: You're not using the URL I gave you.  Put that HTTPS in there!

Comment: mrn@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~$ youtube-dl https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983
[generic] video: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] video: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
mrn@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~$

Comment: i think "https" is not display in comment box. but i put your link as it is.

Comment: now new problem occurred .
1) I can't have root/admin or sudo privilege. and my Ubuntu software center Hang and freezes down. :(

Comment: Would you like to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78577/how-to-download-facebook-videos-by-youtube-dl-in-linux)?

Comment: yes! its better way to explain my question but i does not know how to chat. I think i am new member and do not have CHAT privilege.

Comment: If you link your account to stackoverflow, I can invite you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24059/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-earthmelon).

Comment: -1 This doesn't solve the problem, that the shell interprets some characters in the URL as shell syntax. This has nothing to do with youtube-dl, but with Bash. See the other answer.

Comment: He already tried using a simpler URL, and he's now getting an SSL error, @DavidFoerster.  It's also the first thing I suggest.

Comment: @earthmeLon: Thanks. I see that now and will revert my vote, if you edit your answer. This is what happens, when question authors add relevant infos in comments to answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: @MadhavNikam: As you seem to have a different problem now, that doesn't appear in your question, it would be better, if you either 1) edit your question to include the new problem or 2) ask a new question about the new problem. Otherwise it's going to be hard for other people to follow you, because this type of conversation doesn't fit the question & answer style on this platform.

Comment: <pre>$ sudo apt-get install $(apt-cache depends youtube-dl | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ')</pre><br>
Reading package lists... Done<br>
Building dependency tree       <br>
Reading state information... Done<br>
**E: Unable to locate package <python** <br>

Comment: @MadhavNikam you would have discovered or posting after many months ... use single quotes instead of double quotes to enclose the URL, this worked for me like a charm: youtube-dl -f progressive_hd_src_no_ratelimit 'https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983&set=vb.107925785982&type=2&theater'. I am using latest version of youtube-dl though ...

Comment: @AjayKumarBasuthkar yes! problem was solved and youtube-dl latest updates are very good... and now single quotes are not also require.

Answer (score 11):

You have to escape ampersands (`&`) or **put the whole URL in quotes** since ampersand is one of the special characters that's interpreted by your shell and prevents you from passing the whole URL to youtube-dl. [More on this](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). So just putting it in single quotes will suffice:

```
youtube-dl 'https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983&set=vb.107925785982&type=2&theater'
```

Comment: $ youtube-dl "https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152588878600983&set=vb.107925785982&type=2&theater"
[generic] video.php?v=10152588878600983&set=vb: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] video.php?v=10152588878600983&set=vb: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
$

Comment: @MadhavNikam: Please edit your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 3):

1. right click on the video > click on "show the video URL" > copy the URL there come (NOT the URL of the facebook page).
2. Then, paste the URL copied on the terminal next to 'youtube-dl'

   Ex.:
   youtube-dl https://www.facebook.com/Amhara-Mass-Media-Agency-118697174971952/

Answer (score 3):

This worked in my Linux Mint 18.3-cinammon maybe it could work in yours.You can download video in facebook using youtube-dl by appending Facebook username and password as shown below:

```
youtube-dl <url> --username <YOUR_USERNAME> --password <YOUR_PASSWORD>
```

I hope this help. Thank you.

Comment: I tried, if you have 2FA enable it doesn't work. I also tried with a new account and I get Cannot Parse Data.

Answer (score 1):

```
youtube-dl --username xxxxx --password xxxxx -t -f mp4 'https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx/videos/123456789'
```

Comment: To make this answer clearer, you need to have a Facebook account and you need to provide your Facebook email address and your Facebook password on the command-line in the places marked with `xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

I try download these video through wine+Youtube-dl and its working.
I my case I was install YouTube-dl by Ubuntu software center. Now my software center is not work. Therefore I am unable to Update YouTube-dl through Terminal. **Updated version of YouTube-dl may solve that issue.**
[image: wine+youtube-dl]
**Step1:-** [first install and configure wine.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)
**Step2:-** [download youtube-dl.exe 2016.01.15](http://youtube-dl.org/downloads/2016.01.15/youtube-dl.exe)
**step3:-** copy youtube-dl.exe in to /home/youru_username/.wine/drive_c/folder_for_youtube-dl
[image]
**step4:-** open cmd.exe from /home/madhavnikam/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32
[image]
**Note:-** youtube-dl is a folder in which youtube-dl.exe file is copied.
**step5:-** type cd\ in cmd and set path like c:\youtube-dl\
[image]
More Info 
[1)How to install Wine in Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)
[2)youtube-dl exe version download and copy to C_drive folder of .wine folder.](http://youtube-dl.org/downloads/2016.01.01/youtube-dl.exe)

Comment: Above solution is not proper solution but that solution solve my problem. **Update your Youtube-dl through Terminal or Ubuntu software center it is better solution if your software center is working**

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks. I remember your suggestions for future.

Comment: For everybody else: `youtube-dl` can be run natively in Ubuntu/Linux at least just as easily. No need to involve Wine.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this answer just give for another way if Ubuntu software center is no working or sudo privilege is not available. I agree youtube-dl is natively run in Linux.

Comment: There is a native version of `youtube-dl` available, that doesn't require super-user privileges or package management.

Comment: @DavidFoerster ok thanks for giving unambiguous knowledge and clear doubts about it.