# Gaming on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: games, 15.04

Okay, so when I downloaded Ubuntu I deleted Windows XP because of activation issues. So there's nothing running side-by-side, its JUST Ubuntu. But anyhow, I want to play the games I had on my other OS on this one. For example, games like Sims 2, Hitman Absolution, etc. They read that they're in the ROM, but don't start up the install. So is there some special dealieo I need to download before they install due to the games being made for Windows or Mac? Basically, how do I install and play games on Ubuntu that I had on Windows XP? Thanks y'all.

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Steam and check to see if there is a linux version available?

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

To install and play MS Windows games on Ubuntu (linux), checkout playonlinux.

- https://www.playonlinux.com/en/

  sudo apt-get install playonlinux

Also, there is a commercial product called Crossover for Linux:

- https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux/