# how do I get wine to run on ubuntu 15

Tags: wine

I'm a fairly new user with ubuntu. But What's the best/easiest way to get wine to work. It never seems to work for me.

thanks

Comment: related: [How to install and configure Wine?](http://askubuntu.com/q/316025/184892)

Answer (score -1):

you could try play on linux https://www.playonlinux.com/en/
very easy install and works out of the box most of the times