# Downloading Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: wine, software-center

In the Ubuntu Software Center, I attempted to download the application Wine. However, it reported that there is not a program called wine in my current software sources. I also tried to download it in terminal, and it read:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building Dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is not available, but referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
```

I followed the instructions from the website https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu
for both the command line and ppa repository. 
Is there another way to get this application?

Comment: What Ubuntu release do you use? What messages do you get when running winehq.org instructions?

Answer (score 0):

> I followed the instructions from the website
>   https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

The team behind the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` has changed the package names in the year 2010 or 2011.

Therefore install *Wine 1.7* with

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

More about the installation of Wine [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/316025/367165).

Answer (score 0):

Open `Ubuntu Software Center`, In the `menu bar` click `edit`, and then click `software sources`. This will open a new window named as `software and updates`, click on the `other software` tab. Check `canonical partners` repositories and `independent` repositories too.
Now, open the `command line` and check for updates and install wine...

```
sudo apt-get updates && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once you are done with this, install wine using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

This might help you.