# How to install wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 and don't know how to get wine.Please help and explain in detail.

Comment: In case you didn't notice [my comment](http://askubuntu.com/q/688367): Please take the [tour] and learn how users on the StackExchange network (which this site belongs to) expect you to ask questions and interact. Collecting more down votes will make the site less usable to you.

Comment: @StarOS That is wrong, Ubuntu 12.04 is supported until April 2017, no need to upgrade.

Comment: See [Releases - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current), 12.04 is still supported! Till 2017

Comment: Well, how did you try to install it? What did you do?

Comment: Sorry,the issue has been resolved .I was just trying to make question better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and configure Wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a Terminal by Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

`sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

If you want to install Play on Linux (I recommend you have it : makes install Windows application easy.)

Install Play on Linux by typing in Terminal :

```
wget https://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.2.9/PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb 
sudo dpkg -i PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb
```

Comment: about to come back and edit my post but I see I don't need to because you comment that it working.

Comment: Now in terminal it's showing" sudo dpkg -i PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.de"What to do now/

Comment: Type in sudo dpkg -i PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb and press enter that is  just installing the latest version of play on Linux. if you can't find the shout cut for PlayOnLinux you can start PlayOnLinux by Open a Terminal and typing in playonlinux

Comment: Please provide more info on the error so I can help you.

Comment: I installed playonlinux which started downloading wine1.6 which was aborted so next time when i started to install wine, it displayed two options in manual installation either to install program in a new virtual drive or edit or update an existing application but both further displays an error "Wine seems to have been crashed".Please guide to take further actions.

Answer (score 1):

For WINE my recommendation is to use latest via WINE HQ PPA at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

The reason being its always safe to stay up to latest for more compatibility with games and other programs. WINE is being continuously developed so new games and others stuff gets added regularly.