# How do I find a virus/malware embedded in an mp3?

Tags: mp3, malware

I'm a basic user running Ubuntu 14.04.3 32 bit. I know I have a virus embedded in 1 mp3 I copied from my friend 2 years ago. It's no problem for this system, but it has killed 2 mp3 players & a tablet. The Android scanner couldn't find it. The only virus scanner I can find for Ubuntu is for e-mail. I have 5.4 gigs of mp3's. How do I locate the malware embedded in the mp3?

Comment: You can run the `file` command on these files and see which one doesn't identify as an mp3. Something like `find /path/to/mp3/folder -type f -exec file -Nk {} + | grep -vi audio`

Comment: Can you give me step by step directions on how do I run the file command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using malwarebytes in `wine` may be your solution to the problem. You can install it with `wine` if you do not currently have wine installed you can checkout [how to install wine.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

[Next install malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org)

Install malwarebytes with wine:
Example if you installed:

```
mwb-setup-2.0.1500.exe
```

Type:

```
wine mwb-setup-2.0.1500.exe
```

To run the installer. When installed run the app by opening the unity and typing malwarebytes. Or

```
wine malwarebytes
```

Comment: No problem. Please remember to close the question by clicking the CheckMark