# Steam won't install on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, steam

I had Steam installed and working fine on Ubuntu 15.04 x64.
I upgraded to 15.10, and Steam stopped working.

Because Steam was having trouble with the `mesa-dri:i386` drivers, I uninstalled Steam with `synaptic` and downloaded and installed `Steam.deb` directly from Valve. That produced the same error message, but *will* launch the Steam client.
I then uninstalled that again.

When I do:

```
sudo apt-get install steam

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have read many posts that address this problem mostly on other version of Ubuntu, none of those solutions have solved my situation.

Comment: Try running: `sudo apt-get update` and then: `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and then post any errors in your question, thanks!

Comment: Do this and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/723584/edit) your question with the output: `mkdir ~/Downloads/tmp; cd  ~/Downloads/tmp; apt-get download libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386; sudo dpkg -i *.deb; rm -rf ~/Downloads/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

**Using wine:**
Uninstall steam and fix any broken packages that you may have. You can so this by running `sudo apt-get -f install` then install `wine` if you do not already have it; [dowload steam for Windows.](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe)  and install it in `wine.`
[For more on how to install wine.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

**Other options:**

After uninstalling the current steam installed & running

```
sudo -f install
```

add the following line to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:
deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
```

or
[Get the .deb file from steams official site.](http://store.steampowered.com/about/)