# Setting up Wine ..

Tags: wine, games

I am a completely new to Ubuntu & Linux. I would like to install a PC game, so I understand that I need to use Wine. Also I have the PC game as an .iso file which I assume will need another application to run...

I downloaded Wine 1.8 "from source" from https://www.winehq.org/announce/1.8. I don't really know if it's installed, or if it even needs to be installed. Afterwards I found this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine, which mentions you can download wine from the Software Centre. I'd like to install it from the Software Centre now because I don't know what to do with the files I have from Winehq (not to mention binary packages???). But I am worried that what I already downloaded needs to be removed first. Is this the case??

Comment: To install wine, open the terminal and run: `sudo apt-get remove wine && sudo apt-get install wine`.

Comment: @TshilidziMudau the OP want's to use the software center, not the terminal.

Comment: @Pirouette Welcome to the Ubuntu community, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine) guide has step by step recommended ways of installing **wine**, some of the issues that it has and how to solve them

Answer (score 2):

What you downloaded is the source code of WineHQ, i.e. the code from which you would have to build the program itself.

As you didn't install it, but merely downloaded it, you can simply remove it if you think you don't need to compile it yourself. (And it's not the easiest thing to start with as a beginner in Linux...)

However, there is no need to remove it; you can simply install Wine from the software center without any conflicts.

Best, also install PlayOnLinux, a frontend for Wine. It ships installation scripts for many games and software, and can manage different Wine environments - each with its own Wine version, if necessary - to keep different software apart from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the source code. Installing software from source is and advanced task which involves compiling, getting dependencies, libraries... You won't want it since you can install Wine precompiled, from the Software Center.

If you didn't get to the `make install` part of the source's instructions, no, you didn't install Wine yet. Just remove what you've downloaded.

You can get Wine through the Software Center or run the following command in a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get install wine`

You didn't specify your Ubuntu version, but in 14.04 Wine is is its 1.6 version. But don't bother with having the newest: it didn't change that much. What really matters for gaming is having the appropriate drivers (the best ones are usually the propritary ones). You can get them with "Additional drivers" (look for it in the Dash).

Also have in mind that many games have native Linux versions, and with these you won't need Wine. You can get Steam (through their website or with the Software Center) and enjoy lots of native games such as Team Fortress 2, War Thunder, Left 4 Dead, Dying Light, CSGO and tons of others.

Answer (score 0):

As says the two previous answers, "Source code" is different from "executable code". I have installed Wine 1.8 because I'm fed with my old Wine 1.6.2. I run Ubuntu 14.04. I have typed "sudo apt-get install wine1.8"