# Install .exe on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: 16.04, windows, wine

Hi want to know is it possible to install and use .exe file on Ubuntu  16.04 LTS 64 bit. The software is compatible to Windows 7,8, or 10. (32 or 64bit)

Regards

Comment: Use Wine for that.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: ^ Vagueness is annoying and is impossible to make an answer for. Please tell us what you are trying to use.

Comment: Not all windows programs will work with Wine. programs that rely on device drivers for example will not work. With 'regular' windows programs YMMV. Basically try wine as suggested and if it works then great, if not you may need to look at running the program in a windoze virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

You can install .exe files using Wine.
Follow this, the great one place has full information about wine: [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/a/316029/486406)

Comment: Unable to do, My file want .net 3.5. Tried to install .net 3.5 but unable to install .net 3.5

Comment: @MandeepMavi 
Uninstall all .net 3.5 you installed then setup .net 3.5 x86 only.

Comment: Then I have to do sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 and rm -fr ~/.wine  
export WINEARCH=win32  
export WINEPREFIX="/home/USER/.wine"  
winecfg

Comment: I m able to install wine 1.6 32 bit. tested software like notepad.exe r working. but unable run my exe file , do i need to upgarde wine

Comment: I am getting below error                                                                                                                                                    Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x7db58de8 in 32-bit code (0x100035cf).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:100035cf ESP:0033f564 EBP:0033f588 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:0014e038 EBX:0033fa3c ECX:7db58da0 EDX:0033f57c
 ESI:00000643 EDI:0033f834
Stack dump: