# No sound or controller working on Call of Duty 5 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, wine, games

I should say that I downloaded the game online free before I start but the last time I downloaded from the same place on my Windows 7 it worked,
I already tried reinstalling the sound cards and drivers my sound works on other games and YouTube and so on.

I'm using wine to play the game I have tried a lot of things I've read online already but still haven't fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine) you have a couple of issues which can come from the fact that you are using a 64 bit OS and wine 64 has sound issues with that. Another is games like Limbo and Runner work better on wine 32 with the winetricks directx9 installed (and a couple of more things). All of which you can find on how to solve in the link provided. Even if both games do not mention what is needed @Luis provided all details

Comment: thanks for the reply,i followed your instructions the sound works but the controller stoped working altogether, i have been trying to get it to work but i cant the joystick config screen only gives an option for wireless xbox 360 controllers, also when this happend i lost my system settings and volume but have them back now,im really new to ubuntu as you can tell any help would be great

Comment: just to let people know when i followed the above instructions my pc became unusable