# how to play age of empires 2?

Tags: games, steam

I'm running ubuntu 16.10 and want to play age of empires 2 trough my steam account. every time i launch the game i get a messaghe that says "age of empires II: HD edition is not avaliable on your current plattform".
any solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

You're on Linux. AoE is not available on Linux natively. Use Wine if you wish to play it.

[How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)