# which Wine version am I using?

Tags: wine

I'm wondering which version of Wine I'm using. Because if I type `apt show wine` on terminal:

```
Package: wine
Version: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14
Priority: extra
Section: universe/otherosfs
Source: wine1.6
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 6,144 B
Depends: wine1.6
Homepage: http://www.winehq.org/
Download-Size: 974 B
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)
 Wine is a compatibility layer for running Windows applications on Linux.
 Applications are run at full speed without the need of cpu emulation. Wine
 does not require Microsoft Windows, however it can use native system dll
 files in place of its own if they are available.
 .
 This meta-package always depends on the default version of Wine.
```

but if I type `wine --version` :

```
wine-1.9.22
```

why is there not only one version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using 1.9.22, probably because you have the PPA for it. The command 'wine --version'  always shows the version you are using.

The other version you are seeing, the 1.6.2 is for the package 'wine'  but the 1.9.x package is named wine-staging.

For more information you can also see the following link:

[How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: is there not any problems to use it?

Comment: There is no problem in using 1.9.x I actually use 1.9.x for my gsme testing and app compatibility

Comment: The command is 'wine --version', not 'wine - - version'. Cannot edit though because the edit would be shorter than 6 characters.

Comment: Good catch @stockfisch most probably formatting issue that I did not noticed. Thank you buddy.