# FL Studio on Unity

Tags: unity, music

I'm a producer, and I make music on my PC. My last one crashed, so I bought a new one and it has chromeOS. How can I get the newest FL Studio or FL11 downloaded and ran with Unity?

Answer (score 1):

FL Studio doesn't have Linux version. According to their website, system requirements are:

```
2Ghz Intel Pentium 4 / AMD Athlon 64 (or later) compatible CPU with full SSE2 support. The faster your CPU and more cores it has the more you will be able to do simultaneously. Download and test the trial / demo!

32 or 64 Bit versions of Windows 10/8.0/8.1/7, Vista, XP (service pack 3)

(or) Intel Mac with Boot Camp / Windows. 
Running XP (service pack 3), Vista or Windows 10/8.0/8.1/7 (in 32 or 64 Bit)

(or) Intel Mac with OS X 10.8 or 10.9 for the FL Studio Mac OS X BETA (Crossover Wrapped)
Attention: Yosemite not supported.

1 Gb or more RAM recommended

1 Gb free disk space

Soundcard with DirectSound drivers. ASIO/ASIO2 compatible required for audio recording (FL Studio installs with generic ASIO4ALL drivers)
```

You could try to install it using WINE, but there's no guarantee it will work. Consider using [alternative software which has support for Linux distributions](http://alternativeto.net/software/fl-studio/?platform=linux)

Comment: According to [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=178) it actually works pretty well.

Comment: Depends on version. older versions of QQ also supposed to work well under wine, yet i can't even install one

Answer (score 1):

Actually, FL studio apparently works really well in [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=178) (Gold ratings for the latest Wine version, 1.9).

See [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Please make sure you have an x86/x64 (32-bit or 64-bit) CPU. ARM CPUs in Chromebooks such as Rockchip and Exynos chips **WILL NOT WORK.**