# Ubuntu Wine - cannot find C:\\windows\\system32?

Tags: xubuntu, wine, winetricks

I have installed wine 1.8 and winetricks on my Xubuntu 16.04 but I have the error below when I try to install an exe file:

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Set-up.exe"
```

Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Where is `Set-up.exe` located?

Comment: @muru I created a folder on my desktop and put it there. Shud I put it in a specific place instead?

Comment: then try running `wine ~/Desktop/folder-name/Set-up.exe`

Comment: @teelou Please read the Wine Guide in http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine to know how to execute file outside of the Wine default environment

Answer (score 2):

Run the <kbd>Configure Wine</kbd> application from the launcher or open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and issue the command `winecfg` Either way you will get a Configuration Window for Wine. Insure that you are emulating the right version of Windows for your application and that the settings on all the tabs are sane. Drive Mapping Example Below:

[image: winecfg]

Note: In a typical installation of Wine The directory noted in your question can be found at `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32` and you can examine the content with the command.

`ls ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32`

You can find the location of the Set-up.exe file in your question with the terminal command `find ~/.wine -name Set-up.exe` provided it's anywhere close to where it's supposed to be.

On the off chance you've placed it somewhere outside the Wine drive mapping environment you should be able to locate it with the command `sudo find / -name Set-up.exe`

If anything in this answer is unclear please leave me a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Run winecfg and ensure you have / and ../drive_c mounted in the Drives tab.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide full path (or relative path), wine will only search in "c:\windows\system32"

Just execute your file along with the path

```
# wine ./Set-up.exe
```

Replace `./` with another path if the file is not in your current path.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I ran `~/.wine && winecfg` twice on Ubuntu 22 and no other answers including
Elder Geek's one worked for me.
Instead, I reinstalled wine from the source and it worked perfectly although it took ~30min to build.

```shell
sudo apt remove -y --purge wine wine-stable wine32 libwine wine64
git clone https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine
cd wine
git checkout stable
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt install -y gcc-multilib g++-multilib flex bison libx11-dev:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386
./configure
make -j4
sudo make install
```

To run 32bit apps use `WINEPREFIX=~/.new32prefix WINEARCH="win32" winecfg` or `WINEPREFIX=~/.new32prefix WINEARCH="win32" wine app.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

Related to this issue> 
This is regarding a wine bug https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39403 described in this link
https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/3vuuu9/steam_store_cant_connect_giving_me_black_screen/ .  I want to show installing wine/windows steam games from The Linux Terminal is possible despite the black screen.This allows them to appear in your steam games Library.

There is one problem that must be fixed first and is shown is my work/ research:

In terminal issue:

wine steam.exe

you get this:
wine: cannot find L"C:\windows\system32\steam.exe"

Wine wants any windows executable programs to be installed there for some reason. In my case steam.exe

Solution:

wine start /d "C:\nameoffoldercontainingexecutable" example.exe

For example:

> steamsetup.exe is installed in  C:\Program Files where i like it to be.

Therefore the magic key to issue a command for installing any windows game from the  Linux terminal in wine steam is:

wine start /d "C:\Program Files\steamfoldername" steam.exe -applaunch steamappID#

The steam app ID is found in the URL of the steam game's web page.

wine start /d - Sets the working directory for the executable.

I apologise for combining multiple subjects but to me this is my first post to help others and this is a complicated issue but I hope my idea can be used effectively in a post.

Thank you

**NOTE** For some very rediculous reason when i finish editing this post the windows command line bars shows only 1   \   at a time. They should have 2 for each typed. I can't explain this otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. It appears that you intended this to be a new question regarding the links you provided. Please don't attempt to put questions in answers or answers in questions. Thank you. I recommend that you review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask