# Can't able to add Gionee F103 in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Please any one have any idea that how to use GIONEE F103 mobile to run android applications from android studio.

I am not getting its appropriate driver to install in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If anyone have any link then please share.

Comment: No drivers required, just enable USB debugging.

Comment: I have tried this but device is not showing on target device list while running the activity.

Answer (score 0):

As @CelticWarrior said, for Ubuntu no drivers required to connect your phone. But if that's not working here is the simple way. I also faced the same problem with my Redmi Note 3S. But I installed some of drivers using wine. To do that follow the below steps,

1. Install Wine. To install Wine check this [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/316025/550550) thread.
2. Download the Gionee [drivers](https://gionee.co.in/drivers-for-all-phone-other-than-e7-and-v6l.rar) from their official website. (It's Windows compatible drivers).
3. Now extract the files and right click on AutoRun_install.exe file open with Wine.
4. The installation process goes like the software installation in your Windows OS.
5. After installation connect your phone using data cable and don't forget to enable USB debugging.
6. If it isn't detecting your phone just restart the phone with connected to Computer.
7. And also don't forget to choose MTP option as your connection type.

Comment: I have installed required drivers and did as you instructed but still it's not detecting.

Comment: Connect your phone to computer and turn off (uncheck)  USB debugging and re-enable it. Keep unlocked your phone.

Comment: I have tried this method again n again.. Even i restart the handset again n again but still its not working

Comment: Now I have faced that even other devices r not showing on AVD manager.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved by changing the platform-tools to 23.0.3 from 25.0.0