# How can I install poolshot in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: games

How can I install poolshot for Windows in Ubuntu 16.04?

Poolshot can be downloaded from [the official site](http://poolshot.org/)

Comment: Considering that PoolShot is a Windows application, you would need a compatibility layer (such as Wine) to run the application. This question describes the process of installing Wine: https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine