# How can I run Snapchat on my Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: system-installation

Is there any way to run snapchat on my ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run Snapchat on pc or linux directly. for that you need an emulator called **blustacks**. But currently blustacks is not available in ubuntu. But you can install blustacks with **wine**. Then install snapchat with blustacks.

1. sudo apt-get install wine.
2. Install **blustacks** inside wine.
3. Install snapchat inside blustacks emulator.

you can download blustacks windows version from [here](http://www.bluestacks.com/download.html?utm_campaign=snpcht-ap-us)

if you have any doubt about installing wine read this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

if you have any doubt installing a windows software inside wine read this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/105271/how-to-run-windows-software-on-ubuntu-with-wine/)

if you have any doubt about installing an app in blustacks visit [here](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/206432496-How-to-install-an-app-----)

Comment: This answer no longer works as Snapchat now prevents users from logging into their accounts on Bluestacks systems.