# wine for ubuntu

Tags: updates, wine, files

I installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 17.10; I tried installing wine and was successful up until which version it wanted me to install. (stable, development and what ever the last one was). It said could not find version file on computer. Then i tried downloading the tar file but same error presented itself. I have updated my software and updates and everything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before asking what you're doing wrong, tell as what you have done: what commands, what errors?

Comment: I followed the commands on winehq under ubuntu version of wine. under the lastest release of wine, I was successful in all the commands it showed up until which kind. (stable, development, and the last one.) When typing it, it said it couldn't locate that version file of wine. I tried downloading the wine package file (the tar.gz) but same error.

Comment: I prefer a good red =) if in doubt go with stable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: Follow the link I gave you and post the commands you ran and exact output.  Simply stating it did not work does not give us enough information

Comment: I used sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386, then wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key, sudo apt-key add Release.key, sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/, sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ trusty main', sudo apt-get update. When I typed in sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable or sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel it said it couldn't locate the file.

Comment: sudo apt-get install wine-stable

Comment: No tar ball this is apt

Comment: when i typed it it says package is not available but is referred by another package. might mean its missing,obsoleted or available from another source. 'wine-stable' has no installation candidate

Comment: That is odd search the repo in a browser and co tact winehq

Comment: Contact winehq they maintain the repository and you have followed their advice. https://www.winehq.org/help

Comment: some links on there don't even answer this kind of question or just repeats what i've already typed in.