# Can't play Counter strike 1.6 in 1280 resolution with wine

Tags: nvidia, graphics, wine, games, display-resolution

I have installed and configured wine according this link [Install and configure wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Now my cs 1.6 game runs fine but I can choose max resolution to 960x600 only in widescreen option and 1024x768 in Normal mode.

This crops the game from left and right. I tried to change width in wine **regedit** but once I opened the game again, the registry changes reverted back to default.

Is there any way to configure this in **winecfg gui**? Or what can I do to fix this? I guess there is a way around this because I have installed same things on Desktops with wide Screens and game runs full screen in high resolution.

My laptop is Lenovo Ideapad with max resolution 1366x768

Comment: Can you please describe what cs version are you trying to play?

Comment: I don't know the exact version, but the file name that I downloaded is Counter Strike 1.6 Steam.exe