# Ubuntu 17.10 - Wine installed but missing menu

Tags: wine

I've installed and used Wine countless times over the years but after a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 onto a new PC, Wine seems to install but nothing can be found. It is not in the menu and I can't locate anywhere in the menu settings to enable it. Also, I installed a Windows application but it too has disappeared. No desktop icon and nothing in the menu. Reading whatever I could find here and elsewhere I found nothing that solved the problem! I did install from the command line using the details found on the winehq site and entering winecfg does bring up the settings box.

I was told I needed to install winetricks which I did but still nothing but winetricks in the menu. When trying to install a Windows application and choosing *Properties->Open With* Wine is not an option but running winecfg brings it up so it is clearly running.

I wonder if it's a clue as winecfg outputs many errors even though it does load the interface.

```
$ winecfg
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/don/.wine'
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for$ winecfg
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/don/.wine'
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
wine: configuration in '/home/don/.wine' has been updated. installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
wine: configuration in '/home/don/.wine' has been updated.
```

Comment: since WINE 1.8, it no longer creates menu entries. However, winetricks and q4wine do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: I had already read the post mentioned and it does not answer the question so this is not a duplicate. It's not a matter of knowing how to install wine as I've done it countless times. However, it has always co-operated and never had this problem before now! I finally installed Synaptic Package Manager and even it is having difficulty. 

W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list:1

Comment: You seem to be confusing wine and winetricks, which are not the same thing. Your error message, as posted, is in regards to winetricks, not wine.

Comment: Not at all. I installed both but winetricks seems to do nothing in particular but I was told I had to install it in order to see Wine in the menu even though that's not the case. I see winetricks in the menu but not wine. I used to be able to easily install Wine from the command line, then Windows applications would run and appear in the menu but now they do not.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the specific desktop and menu that this build of Ubuntu uses? It's the 64bit Ubuntu Studio 17.10 and is a fresh install on a new PC. The old PC also had the same version of Ubuntu but had been upgraded many times over the years and somehow used a different desktop and menu.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install a different desktop! Apparently the default that comes with Ubuntu Studio 17.10 does odd things and the one now also better supports my desktop PC's touchscreen display.

Comment: Can you give more details as to which desktop you installed please?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get notices from this forum that there were replies so I saw only by chance the request for information about which desktop was used. I'm not at that location at the moment but I believe it is Gnome which seems to work better (though not really well) with the touchscreen than the others I tried. If there something better yet, I am willing to try it!