# How do I install Twitch on Linux?

Tags: software-installation

When I go onto the Twitch website and download it, it downloads the Windows version and as a result, won't open. How do I install Twitch on Linux 18.2?

Comment: I used the link  @user68186 provided and followed the instructions step by step. I still cant get it installed? Is there any other way that I can do it?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1027873/edit) your question above and copy and paste any error messages you get when you try to install `gnome-twitch`. Without the exact error messages we can't solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 6):

## The best way to install an application is from repositories

In general the Windows executables don't work on Ubuntu. Some Windows software works through Wine. See [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine) for more on how to use Wine. But this is the last resort. You should try to find and install the native version if available.

See [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) for general instructions regarding how to install software in Ubuntu.

## Install gnome-twitch from the repositories

Gnome-twitch is available in the Ubuntu Universe repository. To make sure the Universe repository is enabled, Open **Software & Update** app and mark the check box next to **universe**.

[image]

See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt install gnome-twitch
```

## Alternatively, install the *snap* version of gnome-twitch

The version of software such as `gnome-twitch` is often not the latest in the repositories. `snap` is a different method of software installation and management for Ubuntu that often contains the most recent version. There is a beta version of `gnome-twitch` available via snap. To install this version, enter the following command in the open terminal:

```
sudo snap install --beta gnome-twitch
```

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS this is the only thing I needed to do. If you have not used a `snap` version of any software before, you may need to install `snapd` and associated software with the following command before installing `gnome-twitch`:

```
sudo apt install snapd snapd-xdg-open
```

On my computer I did not need to install Gnome 3.24 and you shouldn't need to install the snap version of Gnome 3.24 for Ubuntu 18.04, as it comes with Gnome 3.28 by default.

To start `gnome-twitch` search for it in the Dash and click on it:

[image]

Reference: [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/08/install-latest-gnome-twitch-0-4-1-via-snap-in-ubuntu-16-04/)