# Ubuntu 18.04 having problems

Tags: 18.04

I've downloaded ubuntu 18.04 from an upgrade.  But I have encountered problems with the upgrade.
1. I can't get no internet I am using my laptop to communicate.  I was getting some errors something like systemd-shim needed to be removed.  My TP Link is not working I have the cd for it.  But when I run the autorun exe it doesn't do anything.

2. I've tried to use a disk that I burned and that doesn't work either.
3. I also get a dpkg error 1 on it don't know what that means.

If anyone can help me please let me know I using a desktop with ASUS motherboard. The tp Link is an archer 4 usb type.  I've tried it out on this laptop and it works fine.

thank you

Comment: `autorun.exe` is a Windows program that won't run in Linux/Ubuntu. What is your TP Link model number?

Comment: please post output of lsusb and ifconfig

Comment: Ok my TP Link is Wireless Network Connection 3 Archer T4U  what is ifconfig?  WinEunuuchs2Unix .  I am using Winders on my laptop to burn a disk for my desktop,

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to assist you with your TP due to your reference to a .exe file and no mention of a Windows emulation software like Wine. I'll edit this if you give more information on that with a better option, however if you are truly in need of a windows execution you will have to use something like wine:

[How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Without detailed information on your error, I can say that it often results in the need to remove files that aren't compatible with the version you are installing or don't work with the package if already present. If you get a list of files that seem to be associated with a previous install attempt, I would suggest attempting to remove them. Just be careful not to remove something that isn't related to your issue or is part of the system. I can give you a more specific answer with more information on the error.

Also, you might try using **gdebi** to install your package instead of **dpkg**. You can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

This is a `.deb` installer that resembles `apt-get` when handling dependencies. I personally almost always use this with `.deb` files and as soon as I get an error, this is what I *always* fall back to using.

Just run `gdebi` in place of `dpkg`

```
gdebi file.deb
```