# Can't install Wine Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, wine

So I started following the instructions on: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

So I did:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

Then after doing an update, I tried to install using:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

But I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.4~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I can't install wine-stable, as it tells me to install wine-stable-i386, which I also can't install because:

```
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                     Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libglu1:i386
                     Recommends: libgsm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 or
                                 libsane1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know how to fix this, please help.

I have also tried doing `sudo apt-get install -f`, but it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Edit: Also did `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
Edit2: wine-staging works

Comment: Please do `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then try again.

Comment: @Hugo I didn't mention that I did that already, forgot, will edit post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: @abu_bua ,I would say that it isn't.
As that thread doesn't specify my problem.

Comment: 2020 and still with troubles? https://itsfoss.com/wine-5-release/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need a version newer than what is in the baseline repos?

If not, remove the ppa you added, and just

`sudo apt install wine-stable`

```
wine-stable:   Installed: 3.0-1ubuntu1   Candidate: 3.0-1ubuntu1   Version table:  *** 3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 [my-local-]mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 [my-local-]mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I don't think I need a newer version, as I run 18.04, and the newest version is for ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: How would you run `wine-staging`? I can't tell if it was installed or not

Comment: Note: I edited to fix a typo.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Make sure you installed FAudio as noted in the [official install guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

### Tutorial

It's FOSS has a great [tutorial on how to install Wine 5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04](https://itsfoss.com/wine-5-release/). It goes like this:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install it easily with the "Software center" application, that is used by every Ubuntu based system. Launch the software, in the searchbox type "Wine" . Install the "Q4Wine" version.
You are ready!
When you start it, you will have the "WineHQ" and other wine based apps - wine mines, wine regedit, wine control panel and other Windows stuff.

Comment: Wine not installing from the Software center or in terminal. Not showing up in my program list. I have tried everything I can think of and still doesn't work.  I updated and upgraded and still nothing.