# Wine 5 refuses to install

Tags: software-installation, wine

I am trying to install Wine 5 on Ubuntu 18. I already did the setup recommended on the Wine wiki (key, repo, etc.). Nothing I try seems to work.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.0~bionic)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.0~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install wine-stable-i386 or -amd64 they also fail.

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
zork@zork-bd5-com:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libfaudio0 but it is not installable
```

Any clues? I already removed Wine 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: By the time you posted this comment I had already found that solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192). You have to install the OpenSUSE repo to get everything you need for Wine 5.0.